# How to set temporary file creation permission in wildly 10

Tags: java-8, wildfly-10, jersey-1.0, java-security

I have enabled security-manager in wildly 10 with below configuration in standalone.xml but when I am starting wildly 10 application server getting following exception(added full exception log) :

```
   13:49:50,667 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
13:49:51,229 SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide, could not b
e instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2018)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2070)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.createMimeConfig(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:121)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.<init>(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:109)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.<init>(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:180)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:283)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:163)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1338)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:231)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:526)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

My product development environment is -jdk8 , jersey 1.19.1 and wildly 10 . Can anyone help me out here please where I am going wrong ?

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0">
            <deployment-permissions>
                <minimum-set>
                    <permission class="java.lang.RuntimePermission" name="getClassLoader" actions="read,write"/>
                    <permission class="java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" name="suppressAccessChecks" actions="read,write"/>
                    <permission class="java.util.PropertyPermission" name="*" actions="read"/>
                    <permission class="java.lang.RuntimePermission" name="accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect" actions="read,write"/>
                    <permission class="java.lang.RuntimePermission" name="accessDeclaredMembers" actions="read,write"/>
                    <permission class="java.lang.RuntimePermission" name="shutdownHooks"/>
                    <permission class="javax.management.MBeanPermission" name="*" actions="queryNames"/>
                    <permission class="javax.management.MBeanServerPermission" name="*"/>
                    <permission class="javax.management.MBeanPermission" name="*" actions="registerMBean"/>
                    <permission class="javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" name="*"/>
                    <permission class="java.io.FilePermission" name="*" actions="read,write"/>
                </minimum-set>
            </deployment-permissions>
        </subsystem>
```

Comment: Is Jersey included in your deployment or did you create a module for it?

Comment: @James , Jersey is included in our deployment we have given Jersey maven dependency and using Jersey as a servlet container .

Comment: You may need to add a `delete` file permissions too.

Comment: @James , I added delete permission too like as below : `<permission class="java.io.FilePermission" name="*" actions="read,write,delete"/>` but still getting same exception . May I know please where i am going wrong ,is this the correct syntax for delete permission?

Comment: @James , I have attached full exception log above for your reference , please if you can guide me where I am going wrong , this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `File.createTempFile()` is attempting to create a file in the directory the `java.io.tmpdir` is set to. In a [`FilePermission`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html) when you use `*` for the name it means "all files in the current directory". What you probably need is `<<ALL FILES>>` for the name.

```xml
<permission class="java.io.FilePermission" name="<<ALL FILES>>" actions="read,write,delete"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot James , I got the idea by seeing your name="<<ALL FILES>>" property which  you mentioned above and referred the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html) and it got solved . God bless you thank you very much for guiding me through out .

Comment: James , this <permission class="java.io.FilePermission" name="<<ALL FILES>>" actions="read,write,delete"/ > was giving me syntax error but instead of this i tried name="/-"  it worked for me , but for future reference if i get this exception java.security.AccessControlException: WFSM000001: Permission check failed (permission "("java.io.FilePermission" "<<ALL FILES>>" "execute")" may i know please how can i avoid it ?

Comment: You could use CLI to set it as the `<` and `>` characters should need to be escaped in the XML. As far as how to avoid issues, there is no formula for it. You just have to handle them as they come up. In this case it's a Jersey issue and WildFly doesn't ship with Jersey.

Comment: Hi James we are facing one issue , we are trying to execute a script from remote file system and getting following exception :

WFSM000001: Permission check failed (permission "("java.io.FilePermission" "<<ALL FILES>>" "execute")" in code source "null" of "null")

even though I have given the required permission set as below :
<pre><code><permission>
  <class-name>java.io.FilePermission</class-name>
  <name>&lt;&lt;ALL FILES&gt;&gt;</name>
  <actions>read,write,delete,execute</actions>
</permission></code></pre>